# Hello, Goodbye, Adios, Aloha

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

I say hello, I say goodbye
One moment I'm low, the next I am high
I can make you see something you did not see
The invisible can be seen through me.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Wave

I say hello, I say goodbye

> To *wave* means to move one's hand to and fro to greet or bid farewell

One moment I'm low, the next I am high

> [image]

I can make you see something you did not see

> Visible light is a wave (has wavelike properties)

The invisible can be seen through me.

> Invisible parts of the electromagnetic spectrum also manifest as waves (infrared, ultraviolet) and invisible phenomena can sometimes also be detected using waves.

Comment: Well done! Correct in every way, although ROT13: Yvarf 1 & 3 jrer zrnag gb or nobhg n unaq jnir - lbh pna jnir ng fbzrbar gb trg gurve nggragvba

Answer (score 5):

> The sun ?

I say hello, I say goodbye

> Dawn and Dusk.

One moment I'm low, the next I am high

> From our perspective the sun goes up then down during the day.

I can make you see something you did not see

> With its light.

The invisible can be seen through me.

> For this one, i suppose it's about the flour or the dust or things like that, in the air that we can only see with the light directly on it.